# How to clear v-date-picker without using cleearable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and nuxt.js to make forms with some text fields and date pickers.

this is one of the child component.

```html
<template>
  <v-menu
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
  >
    <template #activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="date"
        outlined
        readonly
        v-on="on"
      />
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      v-model="date"
      :day-format="(date) => new Date(date).getDate()"
    ></v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: { type: String, default: '' },
    placeholder: { type: String, default: '' },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menu: false,
      selectedDate: this.value,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    date: {
      get() {
        return this.selectedDate
      },
      set(date) {
        this.selectedDate = date
        this.$emit('input', date)
        this.menu = false
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

when the reset button which is on Parent Component clicked, empty string props to this component. `selectedDate` can be reset, but on the `v-text-field` , there is data still.

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add watcher like this:

```
    watch: {
      value: {
        immediate: true,
        deep: true,
        handler(newValue) {
          this.selectedDate = newValue
        }
      }
    },
```